# Android launcher widget issue

Tags: java, android, addition, widget, launcher

I am making my first android launcher based on a stock launcher. I am trying to add widgets onto my main linear layout. But that doesn't work. It doesn't get furter than the onActivityResult() method. Please help me and thanks so much in advance! My code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CREATE_SHORTCUT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CREATE_LIVE_FOLDER = 4;
private static final int REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET = 5;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_APPLICATION = 6;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_SHORTCUT = 7;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_LIVE_FOLDER = 8;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET = 9;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_ANYCUT=10;
private static final int REQUEST_SHOW_APP_LIST = 11;
private static final int REQUEST_EDIT_SHIRTCUT = 12;

    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, R.id.linearLayout);

//Add widgets

void selectWidget() {
    int appWidgetId = this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    addEmptyData(pickIntent);
    Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "Starting activity to pick widget");
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
}

void addEmptyData(Intent pickIntent) {
    ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo> customInfo = 
        new ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_INFO, customInfo);
    ArrayList<Bundle> customExtras = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_EXTRAS, customExtras);
    Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "AddEmptyData");
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
                                Intent data) {
    Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "inside onActivityResult");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "RESULT_OK");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET) {
            Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "calling configureWidget(data)");
            configureWidget(data);
        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET) {
            Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "calling createWidget(data)");
            createWidget(data);
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        Log.d("addWidgetProcedure", "RESULT_CANCELED");
        int appWidgetId = 
            data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}

private void configureWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = 
        mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {
        Intent intent = 
            new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET);
    } else {
        createWidget(data);
    }
}

public void createWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = 
        mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    AppWidgetHostView hostView = 
        mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    linearLayout.addView(hostView);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Adding widget", 15).show();
}
```

When i press menu->add widget, it calls the selectWidget() method.

All the logcat output from when i press menu->add widget to i have selected one.

```
07-11 14:38:27.178: W/KeyCharacterMap(1751): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
07-11 14:38:27.178: W/KeyCharacterMap(1751): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/bravo-keypad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='bravo-keypad'
07-11 14:38:27.178: W/KeyCharacterMap(1751): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-11 14:38:28.348: D/addWidgetProcedure(1751): AddEmptyData
07-11 14:38:28.348: D/addWidgetProcedure(1751): Starting activity to pick widget
07-11 14:38:28.428: D/addWidgetProcedure(1751): inside onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET = 9;
```

With:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET = 0;
```

Comment: doesn't work, i made a log code in each method, and as far as i can see, it doesn't get further than the onActivityResult() method

Comment: If it reaches the "if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {" line, you can debug to see what is the value of your "resultCode".
Go on moving like that, change your variable values till you reach "createWidget(data);"

Comment: I have already done that, actually, the resultCode is 0, when i logged the data on the onActivityResult() method after the first log. The logcat output said: resultCode: 0

Comment: I hope you've replaced "RESULT_OK" with 0 and tried if it works, did you?